# Blender Python cannot call class; AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'operator'

Tags: python, blender

i'm currently trying to teach myself how to create blender tools, so i tried to create a simple batch export tool using the template blender provides for that (aka everything in the execute is just blenders stuff, i tried it and that part works). I've been following some tutorials but i'm stopped on an error that blender is not explaining to me at all.
This is all i get now:

```
line 9, in <module>
}
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'operator'
```

Here is the code i have, i tried several indent error options or moving the register around a the beginning of the code but it's just not working out. Any tip or help on what's wrong with my class and register stuff is greatly appreciated!!

```
# exports each selected object into its own file
import bpy
import os
class EXP_fbxbatchexport(bpy.types.operator):
   """Tooltip here"""
   bl_idname = "mesh.fbxbatchexport"
   bl_label = "FBX Batch Exporter"


#def invoke(self, context, event):
 
   def execute(self, context):
    
       # export to blend file location
       basedir = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)

       if not basedir:
           raise Exception("Blend file is not saved")

       view_layer = bpy.context.view_layer

       obj_active = view_layer.objects.active
       selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

       bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

       for obj in selection:

           obj.select_set(True)

           # some exporters only use the active object
           view_layer.objects.active = obj

           name = bpy.path.clean_name(obj.name)
           fn = os.path.join(basedir, name)

           bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=fn + ".fbx", use_selection=True)

           # Can be used for multiple formats
           # bpy.ops.export_scene.x3d(filepath=fn + ".x3d", use_selection=True)

           obj.select_set(False)

           print("written:", fn)

       view_layer.objects.active = obj_active

       for obj in selection:
           obj.select_set(True)
    
       return {'FINISHED'}    
def register():
   bpy.utils.register_class(EXP_fbxbatchexport)
def unregister():
   bpy.utils.unregister_class(EXP_fbxbatchexport)
#this function only calls to register the function when the code is actually run
if __name__ == '__main__':
   register()
```

Edit: opened system console and added the module operator attribute error mssage, I tried to find solutions but nothing really helps me

Comment: Have you seen the message in the system console in blender? There should be additional information in Windows > Toggle System Console.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it
i wrote bpy.types.operator in the class line instead of bpy.types.Operator :))) i go into my corner tysm for the support tho!!!